# Two divs in the same line

Tags: html, css

I have a box that contain some text and another box that contain a video.
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2VuwX/)
Codes:
CSS:

```
.bluebox{
    background-color: #1EAECE;
}
.orangebox{
    background-color: #FF8800;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top: -13px;">
<div class="bluebox" style="display: table-cell;width: 52.2%;">
    <div class="title">Usage</div>
    <ul>
        <li>Moisten with warm water to activate the ingredients.</li>
        <li>Apply the bar directly on face & body.</li>
        <li>Massage the creamy texture into your skin.</li>
        <li>Allow the emulsion time to permeate into the skin.</li>
        <li>Rinse off.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Suitable for Face wash, Body wash, Shaving, Sensitive areas, Intimate parts, Shower & Bath.</p>
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell;width: 0.7%;"></div>
<div class="orangebox" style="display: table-cell;width: 47.3%;">
    <video width="418" src="http://brexes.com/Images%20and%20Videos/GamilaSecretVideo.mp4" controls></video>
</div>
</div>
```

The first box that contain text have a huge space on the top, I want to remove this space and set the two divs in the same line.
So here's how it looks like:
[image]

Here's how it should be like:
[image]

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to blue and orange divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a basic:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to your class ".bluebox"